# Tab Navigator On focussed

Tags: react-native

I have a TabNavigator

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Test: {
        screen: SCA,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                return (
                    <FAIcon 
                        name='screen1'
                        size={25}
                        color={tintColor}
                    />
                );
            }
        })
    },
    Screen2: {
        screen: SCB,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'screen2',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                return (
                    <MIcon
                        name='account-circle'
                        size={25}
                        color={tintColor}
                    />
                );
            }
        })
    },
    screen3: {
        screen: MYSCREEN,
        navigationOptions: () => ({
            title: 'dd',
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => {
                return (
                    <MIcon
                        name='account-circle'
                        size={25}
                        color={tintColor}
                    />
                );
            }
        })
    }
}, {
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    tabBarOptions: {
        showIcon: true,
        showLabel: true,
        inactiveTintColor: Colors.blue,
        activeTintColor: Colors.redColor,
        pressColor: Colors.redColor,
        indicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.redColor },
        style: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.white
        }
    }
});
```

Basically I have tab navigator with 3 tabs. Whenever screen3 is focussed via tab button press or by swiping how can I get to know in MYSCREEN that this screen is focussed again.(Screen looks similar to playstore app with selecting screen on tab as well as swiping)

```
Class MYSCREEN extends React.Component{

//some function like on onfocus?

}
```

I tried searching it showed onFocusComponent will work but it didn't.
What should I do?

Comment: What are you using for navigation?

Comment: TAB Navigator, react-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `react-navigation` you can use listeners on the navigation lifecycle events. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

There are four events you can subscribe to:

> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

You can subscribe to as many of them as you want. Here is an example of using `didFocus`. You could easily replicate this for all that you require.

So in each of the screens of your TabNavigator, you can add the following:

```
componentDidMount () {
  // add listener 
  this.didFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', this.didFocusAction);
}

componentWillUmount () {
  // remove listener
  this.didFocusSubscription.remove();
}

didFocusAction = () => {
  // do things here when the screen focuses
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot sir, I Didn't new about adding the listener part.:-)

Comment: @NimishBansal you're welcome. If you feel my answer helped you can you mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks :)

Comment: yes sorry for not accepting at that time.My connection lost as soon as I pressed the tick, Thanks a lot again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withNavigationFocus`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation-focus.html) HOC which will add `isFocused` prop to your screen component's props then catch that prop in `getDerivedStateFromProps` method and check if isFocused is `true`and then return a new state so that the component will render again.

Comment: I think that can help to know if component is focussed or not, but I was searching for focusChangeListener?.Is that possible too with this?

Comment: Yes, it is, but make sure to catch that prop in `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method and check if `isFocused` is true and then return a new state so that the component will render again. i did update my answer.